# How do I cut a new crawlspace access in a brick foundation?

Tags: foundation, crawlspace

When my house was built, the crawlspace access was put on the high side of the property, which I'm sure gave the subcontractors the easiest access for HVAC, wiring, etc.  But there is very little useful storage space.  At the low end of the house, I can almost stand up straight in the crawlspace, but there is not access.  I would **love** to be able to use all that space, but I can't get to it on a day to day basis.  So I would like to have a new crawlspace access door installed on that end of the house.

Tips? Warnings?

The foundation is brick.  I don't need a full door necessarily.  I am open to any advice.

Comment: You can cut it with a masonry saw. Warnings would be to make sure you're not cutting out too much as to weaken the integrity of the wall as it is supporting the house.

Answer (score 3):

I think this deserves to have an engineer take a look and give you an opinion. Removing a large portion of the foundation is not something you want to mess with without a plan. Plus if you're going to bother to do it, you might as well make it a real door so that you can actually get boxes in there or something.

As an alternative idea, it might be easier to put a trap door in your floor somewhere above the crawlspace at a convenient location. Obviously this has its own structural considerations, but it might be easier and would let you avoid messing with the foundation.